# Easy way to test usefulness of data for stock market analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset

I have a lot of data (gigs) that may be useful in predicting equity prices. I can import these as a series of features (columns) in a table where the companies are rows. I have time series information too.

I have some machine learning experience but no experience as a trader.

Is there some software or platform where I could easily import my data and it could backtest/forward test my data to see if it's useful?

I understand that any machine learning system that's out there in public won't outperform the market enough to cover brokerage fees, but given my data, there's a chance it would. So I probably don't need state of the art in machine learning but I'd like to find a solution where I don't spend the next 6 months learning the stock market. I'd rather spend that time getting feedback on, and iterating on the input data, because as a data-oriented developer, that's where I can add value.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: quant.stackexchange.com has some questions about machine learning with applications to equity markets. You might find related material there, though that site is primarily for professionals.

Comment: @John Thanks--it turns out this question was cross-posted at quant and was closed there as being off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have everything in a database, then Weka is a nice tool for proof-of-concept tests. It's open source, free, contains most mainstream algorithms and it can retrieve data from a database through a JDBC connector.

The only drawback is that it's a little old so it's quite horrible to code against, and the interface isn't the most slick.

According to the documentation, it has some tools for time series analysis, but I've not tried them myself.